# How to use NSURLDownload

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

```
- (IBAction)startDownloadingURL:(id)sender
{
    // create the request
    NSURLRequest *theRequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com/index.html"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    // create the connection with the request
    // and start loading the data
    NSURLDownload  *theDownload=[[NSURLDownload alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if (!theDownload) {
        // inform the user that the download could not be made
    }
}
```

When I run the simulator, I got an error:

> NSURLDownload undeclared, first use in
>   this function.

Where can I import the library of NSURLDownload.

Answer (score 10):

**[NSURLDownload not on iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839) see the note:**

> iPhone OS Note: The NSURLDownload
>   class is not available in iPhone OS as
>   downloading directly to the file
>   system is discouraged. Use the
>   NSURLConnection class instead. See
>   “Using NSURLConnection” for more
>   information.

Have a look at Apple's documentation about [URL loading system](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165) and [NSURLDownload](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLDownload.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001839).

Comment: I assume by simulator you mean iPhone simulator so you are compiling this for iPhone not desktop.

Answer (score 2):

If you've just looking to grab the contents of the page:

```
NSData *pageContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]];
```

Comment: Hi @christo16, would you mind see my question here? I just wonder whether there is a better technique : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950384/why-nsdata-datawithcontentsofurl-sometimes-return-null-value

Comment: @christo16 You're missing `NSURL` before `URLWithString`, that portion should be: `[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]`