# Why NSData dataWithContentsOfURL sometimes return NULL value?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am gratefully thanks for the article [Convert NSData bytes to NSString?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/550405/convert-nsdata-bytes-to-nsstring), especially for @christo16. I was previously dependent on ASIHttpRequest just to get value from PHP server. Now using by just this line of code :

```
NSString *pageContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.apple.com"]]
```

I can get the functionality that I wanted.

But why is sometimes that line cause pageContents to be NULL. I already change that line into this :

```
NSString *fullUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.apple.com"];
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:fullUrl];
NSData *pageContents;
NSString *response = NULL;

while(response==NULL)
{
    pageContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:fullUrl]];
    response = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[pageContents bytes]];
    NSLog(@"content = %@", response);
}
```

Is there any better way of doing this? Up until now, I have no problem. I just wonder whether there is a more elegant way of achieving the same result

Thanks

Comment: The downside of that one-liner is that it blocks your UI, possibly for a long time. The loop is even worse: if the server is not responding to connections, then it would block the UI effectively forever (until SpringBoard gets fed up and kills your process).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will return `nil` if there is an error retrieving the data.

You can use the `dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error:` message to find out why it's returning nil. The error will be returned in the `NSError*` pointer that you pass.

Comment: thanks @Brigham for that info. But, the problem is, it sometimes null, sometimes not. So, I just force it to try it until it's not null. If using dataWithContentsOfURL:options:error, how do you handle such?

Comment: @swdev: You look at the error to find out what went wrong, and react appropriately to what went wrong. Usually this will be presenting the error to the user.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the picture is too big or url is incorrect.

```
NSError* error = nil;
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yourURL options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
if (error) {
   NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
} else {
   NSLog(@"Data has loaded successfully.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check your network connection. If it is connected then the problem will solve.